# Error during SELECT sql query between Azure SQL DBs

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.1

I have .NET Core app with EF Core.

I use Azure SQL DBs.

I have one main DB "Catalog" and multiple others.

I'm trying to populate one table in multiple DBs but value I need to get from main DB "Catalog".

I did the following migration:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] "
                     + "(Name, Description)"
                     + " VALUES "
                     + "((SELECT param1 FROM [Catalog].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE DB_NAME() = CONCAT(param1, '-', param2)), 'some description')");
```

But in result I see:

> Reference to database and/or server name in 'Catalog.dbo.Table1'
>   is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

So I can't execute `SELECT` queries between Azure DBs? Or my sql is wrong? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Cross-database querying is tricky and you are probably searching for [Elastic Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview)

Comment: Hi take a look https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query remote database, you can use the [Azure SQL Database elastic query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-overview).

For example

1. create a certificate for the remote database

```
 CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<master_key_password>';
 CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL RemoteDBCred
 WITH IDENTITY = '<username>',
 SECRET = '<password>';
```

2. Create an external data source fro the remote database

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyRemoteDBSource WITH
    (TYPE = RDBMS,
    LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME = '<>',
    CREDENTIAL = RemoteDBCred,
) ;
```

3. Create an external table with the data source

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[<>]
( 


)
WITH
( DATA_SOURCE = MyRemoteDBSource)
```

4. Query the table

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical) and the [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/cross-database-query-in-azure-sql-database/ba-p/369126)